# javascript library not loaded in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, chromecast

Im including the google cast external javascript library. When I run with ionic serve it works good, but when I run the app in the phone, the library is not loaded. Debugging can see that :

https://cdn-enterprise.discourse.org/ionicframework/uploads/default/original/3X/a/d/ad4c985f45c1c538bdfbfbb02d10141b6929e1d5.png

The "http" is replaced by "file"!
I tried to include the libraries with that code:

script src="//www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1">

and with type="text/javascript" added; but all codes replaces http by file, and the library is not loaded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the app do not add cdn files starting with "//:", add them like "http://".

If its possible download those files and keep them in directory, after that give directory path to file.

e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/library.js">`